# EC2 cost after free tier ends

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I'm using the AWS free tier to run my EC2 t2.micro instance with 30GB EBS storage.

My question is - when the Free Tier time will end, how much I will pay in total for running my EC2 instance?

I understand that the EC2 payment is ~$100/year, but what about the storage it's using? A huge part of the 30GB is AWS programs and the Windows OS, so I will pay this storage in addition to the EC2 payment?

So the actual total bill will be $100 (EC2) + $18 (30GB of EBS)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to pricing of a 3rd-party service, not to software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon has a pricing calculator to help you determine monthly costs. For you example in the us-east-1 without any data transfer costs, your monthly fee will be $15.45. This includes $12.45 for the T2.micro Windows instance and $3.00 for 30GB of EBS storage.

[Amazon Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)